# How does the ASP.NET Web API project template use this HelpPage area like it weren't an area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-areas

Open a new ASP.NET Web API project in Visual Studio 2017 Community (or whichever edition) and run it and you'll see a welcome page with an **API** hyperlink.

Click the hyperlink and it takes you to the url `http://localhost:<port>/Help`.

That's the `Index` action on the `HelpController` in the `HelpPage` area.

However, what I am confused by is the following:

1. There is no area registration for the `HelpPage` area.
2. This `ActionLink` call is outright wrong. It says, "Please call the `Index` action on the `HelpController` within the default area-less area."

**From _Layout.cshtml in the project root**

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("API", "Index", "Help", new { area = "" }, null)</li>

That's outright abusive. How does that work?
```

3. Wait, shouldn't the default route for this action be `localhost:<port>/HelpPage/Help/[optional:Index]`? Where's the route configuration for this area? If it is absent, the routing should go by the only default route declared in the root, area-less area, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `Areas\HelpPage\HelpPageAreaRegistration.cs` file taking care of the area registrations, shown below.
*(I'am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise edition.)*

Notice that the `HelpPageAreaRegistration` class registers the route `Help/{action}/{apiId}` that uses a constant url-template part `Help` which doesn't match with the name of the area `HelpPage`.
(By convention, this route would have been `HelpPage/{controller}/{action}/{id}`.)

Doing so, you don't have to (and must not) specify the area name in the `@html.ActionLink`, as this controller has an 'explicit' route, which avoids conflicts with other routes, including those from the default area.
This route must be configured from within the `AreaRegistration` and not in `RouteConfig` in order for the views to be resolved from the appropriate views folder within this `HelpPage` area.

```
public class HelpPageAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get{ return "HelpPage"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "HelpPage_Default",
            "Help/{action}/{apiId}",
            new { controller = "Help", action = "Index", apiId = UrlParameter.Optional });

        HelpPageConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn! How did I miss seeing that.